# Problem with pdfstrcmp

Tags: tikz-pgf, xstring

i'm trying to store a three-digit parameter (101) in three different variables by using substrings. Depending on the input, i want to put one to three different icons in the upper right corner of an rectangle. The content of the substrings looks fine, but the following error prevented the correct output.

Argument of \@xs@StrMid has an extra }. \end{info}

If i'm using three parameter it works, but the goal is to do it with only one parameter.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\definecolor{main-color-05}{HTML}{BF3100}
\definecolor{dark-color}{HTML}{2B2B2B}
\definecolor{light-color}{HTML}{F6F6F6}

\tikzset{
    box/.style={rectangle, fill=light-color, inner sep=10pt},
    border/.style={draw=main-color-05, line width=2pt},
}

% does not work
\NewEnviron{info}[1]{
    \newcommand{\posone}{\StrMid{#1}{1}{1}}
    \newcommand{\postwo}{\StrMid{#1}{2}{2}}
    \newcommand{\posthree}{\StrMid{#1}{3}{3}}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[box] (m) {%
            \begin{minipage}{0.925\textwidth}
            {\LARGE\bfseries\color{dark-color}Lorem Ipsum}\hfill \posone\postwo\posthree
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\posone}{1}=0
                \,first-icon
            \fi
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\postwo}{1}=0
                \,second-icon
            \fi
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\posthree}{1}=0
                \,third-icon
            \fi\\
            \BODY
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \draw[border] (m.south west) -- (m.north west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}

% work
\NewEnviron{info1}[3]{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[box] (m) {%
            \begin{minipage}{0.925\textwidth}
            {\LARGE\bfseries\color{dark-color}Lorem Ipsum}\hfill
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{1}=0
                \,Icon1
            \fi
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{1}=0
                \,Icon2
            \fi
            \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#3}{1}=0
                \,Icon3
            \fi
            \\
            \BODY
            \end{minipage}
        };
        \draw[border] (m.south west) -- (m.north west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
    % does not work
    \begin{info}{321}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \end{info}

    % work
    \begin{info1}{1}{0}{1}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    \end{info1}
\end{document}
```

I hope someone can help me.
And sorry for my bad english.

Mfg seeking help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common misunderstanding of how `xstring` works; the code `\StrMid{#1}{1}{1}` is *not* the first item in the string, but the instructions for getting it. The package provides a trailing optional argument for storing the result:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\definecolor{main-color-05}{HTML}{BF3100}
\definecolor{dark-color}{HTML}{2B2B2B}
\definecolor{light-color}{HTML}{F6F6F6}

\tikzset{
    box/.style={rectangle, fill=light-color, inner sep=10pt},
    border/.style={draw=main-color-05, line width=2pt},
}

% does not work
\NewEnviron{info}[1]{%
  \StrMid{#1}{1}{1}[\posone]%
  \StrMid{#1}{2}{2}[\postwo]%
  \StrMid{#1}{3}{3}[\posthree]%
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box] (m) {%
      \begin{minipage}{0.925\textwidth}
        {\LARGE\bfseries\color{dark-color}Lorem Ipsum}\hfill\posone\postwo\posthree
         \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\posone}{1}=0
           \,first-icon
         \fi
         \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\postwo}{1}=0
           \,second-icon
         \fi
         \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\posthree}{1}=0
           \,third-icon
         \fi\\
         \BODY
       \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw[border] (m.south west) -- (m.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

Works!
\begin{info}{321}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores 
et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea 
rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{info}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid the single specifier `[h]` or you'll get into troubles if the figure cannot be placed in that place.

On the other hand, you can completely avoid `xstring`: add

```
\newcommand{\extract}[1]{\extractaux#1...\extractaux}
\def\extractaux#1#2#3#4\extractaux{%
  \def\posone{#1}%
  \def\postwo{#2}%
  \def\posthree{#3}%
}
```

and do

```
\NewEnviron{info}[1]{%
  \extract{#1}%
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, fist of all thank you very mutch. It now works as i hoped. And thanks for the hint: i added the missing specifier to the figure-environment. But can you explain me exactly what you are doing in the second example where you describe the avoid of `xstring`? I dont understand the `\extractaux`.

Comment: @user91942 `\extract` calls a macro with delimited arguments: it has four arguments, but the fourth is “everything up to and excluding `\extractaux`. So the first three arguments grab (in the test case) `3`, `2`, and `1` respectively because `\extractaux321...\extractaux` is called. The three dots are a safeguard against faulty input (for instance if the argument is only two character long); they'll be discarded because we do nothing with `#4`. Low level technique, but effective.